# Basic-Blocks in CUDA

Tags: cuda, parallel-processing, nvcc, ptx

Is there a way to see the basic-block information for a CUDA source code? 
I am trying to compile a CUDA code so that the output it gives me is a file with all the basic-blocks listed. But so far,I haven't been able to find any option in nvcc which allows me to do that.

If we can extract the basic-block information from the IR (PTX), that also helps.

Comment: What do you mean by ,"basic block information "?

Comment: Its okay, I found it. I was basically looking for a control flow graph sort of thing from the CUDA code. We can do it through nvdisasm it seems.

Comment: Please add an answer to your question describing your solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was looking for a way to extract the basic-blocks or the control flow graph of a CUDA source. It seems there is a way, but we get the control flow in the form of an intermediate representation (PTX).

The "nvdisasm" has a way to extract the control flow graph of a kernel. More information can be found here:
http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-binary-utilities/index.html#axzz3lONRPxm5